# Multiple Laravel 8 column uniqueness validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a problem with validating multiple column in laravel 8.

Here is my code:

**controller**

```
$validator = $messages = [
                'file' => 'This user has current file name',
            ];
$fileName = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        [
            'file' => [
                'required', 'max:8000',
                Rule::unique('files')->where(function ($query) use ($userId, $fileName) {
                    return $query->where('userId', $userId)
                        ->where('name', $fileName);
                }),
            ],
        ],
        $messages
    );
```

**View**

```
<input type="file" className="form-control" name="file" id="file" />
```

**DB Structure**

id
userId
name

and I got

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'file' in 'where clause'

I want each user only have one file name and I wanna do it with laravel 8 validation.

**Note:** I made my table unique but I want to validate it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom validation

```
$fileName = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        [
            'file' => [
                'required', 'max:8000',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($userId, $fileName){
                    $exists = \DB::table('files')->where('userId', $userId)->where('name', $fileName)->count();
                    if ($exists) {
                        $fail('This user has current file name');
                    }
                },
            ],
        ],
        $messages
    );
```

or Use the Unique rule by using another array than `$request->all()`

```
$fileName = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$validator = Validator::make(
        ['name' => $filename, 'file' => $request->file], //notice the change HERE
        [
            'file' => ['required', 'max:8000']
            'name' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('files')->where(function ($query) use ($userId, $fileName) {
                    return $query->where('userId', $userId);
                })
            ],
        ],
        $messages
    );
```