# Laravel validation rule: unique with additional condition

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application, in the `users` table I have an additional column named `platform`.

When new users sign up, they pick one of three platforms: site1, site2, site3. Now, I want to validate that the entered email is unique, but **only for the selected platform**.

For example, let's say a user exists with `email = john@doe.com` and `platform = site1`.

Then, if you go to the register form and input...

```
email = john@doe.com
platform = site2
```

...you should be able to sign up.

But if you enter...

```
email = john@doe.com
platform = site1
```

...you should see an error message because the user `john@doe.com` already exists for the platform `site1`.

In my validator, I've been unable to set this up. If I do this then it returns an error even when platforms are different (as expected):

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => ['required', 'unique:users'],
]);
```

But if I do this, in an attempt to group the unique condition by platform, then all signups are allowed even when platforms are the same:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => ['required', 'unique:users,platform,site1'],
]);
```

Is there a way to set this up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Laravel 8 column uniqueness validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68271656/multiple-laravel-8-column-uniqueness-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify where conditions in the unique rule.

```
'email' => [
   "required",
   Rule::unique('users')->where(fn ($query) => $query->where('platform', request()->platform)), //assuming the request has platform information
];
```

And, to ensure uniqueness at the database level, you might want to define the email and platform as a composite unique key

In the migration:

```
$table->unique(['email','platform']);
```

Reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique under the headline: Adding Additional Where Clauses:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#creating-indexes to get more information about creating composite indexes in Laravel.

Advice: RTFM

Comment: Thanks. Quick follow up though, how do I combine this with my other email-related rules (`required` field etc). It doesn't seem like I can just replace `unique:users` with your solution.

Comment: Yes you can....updated answer.