# Laravel Form Request Validation to Avoid Duplicate Date Entry

Tags: php, laravel

here I'd like to find a way how to avoid duplication of data using Form Validation Request. Here's my Form Request Validation so far:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'staff_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:staffs,id'],
        'date' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:worktime,date'],
        'time_started' => ['required', 'date_format:H:i'],
        'time_ended' => ['required', 'date_format:H:i', 'after:time_started'],
    ];
}
```

What I want is to prevent create data if `staff_id` and `date` has been recorded before. But in my code, it work with an issue that is I can't to create a new data on same date with different staff_id. Here's the error:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "date": [
            "The date has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in the Validation level?

Comment: Same concept as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73304076/3532758  You can perhaps create a composite unique key.

Answer (score 0):

```
return [
        'staff_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:staffs,id'],
        'date' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:worktime,date,'.$staff_id.',staff_id'],
        'time_started' => ['required', 'date_format:H:i'],
        'time_ended' => ['required', 'date_format:H:i', 'after:time_started'],
    ];
```